# XMPP + pubsub + ajaxpush

Tags: ajax, xmpp, push, publish-subscribe

I needed to implement ajax push for real-time updates if there is a database update, group chat etc. As far i have come to know after researching on the net that methods like having a comet server, pubsubhubub & some series of ajax hack and turnarounds like long polling etc.

I found my requirements were full filled using XMPP by strophe and flxhr and bosh.

My queries :

1. which is the best method keeping in mind the speed , real time nature, opensource & scalability
2. while trying to send  xmpp stanza for creating a node to pubsub.jabber.org it sends a reply with error saying remote-server not found. How can i solve this issue.
3. A idiotic sounding query - I am using openfire as xmpp server and a public bosh service at http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind. now in future when i will upload my website to say bigdaddy on some domain... does bigdaddy etc run a xmpp server or other requirement for my website to be functional
4. If u have any links to tutorials etc in ajax push pls add those links.
5. what are future prospects of xmpp? which technique is gaining the most popularity for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Strophe.js](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs) implements [XMPP over BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html), so your first question boils down to Strophe.js and (some [XMPP server](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/)) vs. [flxhr](http://flxhr.flensed.com/) and some web server infrastructure.  I'm biased towards the XMPP/BOSH solution (since I live in that world), but since flxhr requires Flash, and BOSH can be implemented in a [way](http://metajack.im/2010/01/19/crossdomain-ajax-for-xmpp-http-binding-made-easy/) that supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), I don't see the advantage.
2. This is likely a setup problem with your server.  You need to support inbound connections, typically on port 5269/tcp, and have your DNS set up correctly.  [XEP-220](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0220.html) may provide some important clues for you.
3. For production, you should run your own server, and your own BOSH service.  Jack could look at all of your traffic if he desired.
4. Google says: http://frishit.com/2010/06/setting-up-xmpp-bosh-server/
5. If you want opinions like this, maybe you should start a separate question, but it's likely to get closed as non-technical on stackoverflow.  Maybe one of the other StackExchange sites would be a better fit.